# Getting a negative magnitude when solving for magnitude using the formula for angle between two vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

> $\vec{u},\vec{v}$ are two given vectors. It is known that
>
> $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = 5, \ \ \ ||\vec{v}|| = 2, \ \ \  \theta=2\pi/3$
>
> Find $||\vec{u}||$

I am using the formula for the angle between two vectors to solve for the
magnitude of one of my vectors. Work is included in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMguf.jpg).

After using the formula for the dot product I get $||\vec{u}|| = -5$

How am I getting a negative magnitude when I solve for the magnitude of one of my vectors?

Do I simply take the absolute value of this?

Comment: The dot product between the two vectors shouldn't be positive if the angle between then is greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem statement is somewhat messed up. The sign of the dot product defines if the angle between the two vectors is acute or obtuse. So if the dot product is $5$ then the angle cannot be $2\pi/3$.

Tell them to make up their mind.
They should either change the dot product to $-5$ or the angle to $\pi/3$
(in the problem statement, I mean).